# How to trigger element.on('mouseleave') in a Uint Test to call my AngularJS function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, karma-jasmine

I want to call `myFunction`. Then I want to verify it was called with a Unit Test.

Javascript:

```
var self = this;

self.myFunction= function myFunction() {
    // do stuff
};

self.onClickChange = function onClickChange() {
    $('.checkBox').on('mouseleave', function(){
        self.myFunction();
    });
};
```

I have tried this test:

```
it('should call myFunction', inject(function ($compile, $rootScope) {
    spyOn(this.instance, 'onClickChange').and.callThrough();
    spyOn(this.instance, 'myFunction').and.callThrough();

    this.instance.onClickChange('messageBoard');

    var scope = $rootScope.$new(),
    element = $compile('<md-checkbox class="checkBox"></md-checkbox>')(scope);

    element.triggerHandler('mouseleave');
    scope.$digest();

    expect(this.instance.myFunction).toHaveBeenCalled();
}));
```

I have also tried using

```
scope.$broadcast('mouseleave');
```

And

```
var event = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
event.initEvent('mouseleave', true, true);
$('.checkBox').dispatchEvent(event);
```

And this instead of the last line in the previous three lines:

```
document.body.dispatchEvent(event);
```

How can I get `.on('mouseleave')` to work and ferify that `myFunction` has been called?

Comment: @dimwittedanimal the post you provided did not work for me. It is in Angular 2, I am using AngularJS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several things here. First, to answer your immediate question, you are calling: `this.instance.onClickChange('messageBoard');` before you have created any DOM. So, you are going to try adding the click handler to absolutely nothing.

You need to add the click handler only after you create the DOM when you call compile.

But, there's another problem. You are compiling the directive and creating a DOM element, but it is not rooted in the document, so using the jquery `$` on the document will not work.

*It is bad style to use jQuery selectors in angular.*

You could do something like this, where you use the `$element` of the current scope.

```
var self = this;
var $element = getElement(); // do some magic to get the current element

self.myFunction= function myFunction() {
    // do stuff
};

self.onClickChange = function onClickChange() {
    $element.on('mouseleave', function(){
        self.myFunction();
    });
};
```

And then your tests could work in the same way. The difference is that the `$element` never needs to be added to the DOM in order for the code to work.

But really, I would avoid this whole approach. You should not be using jQuery inside of angular. That is an outdated style. Instead, I recommend using `ng-click` to add the handler directly to the DOM.